# Ubuntu 12.04 - Desktop crashes constantly

Tags: unity

What logs do I check to find out why my desktop is crashing back to the login screen so much?  It happens multiple times a day.

Thank you.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

One of the best logs to start with is /var/log/syslog. You might also get some clues from the Xorg.0.log as well.

Comment: This is in regards to Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.  It is relevant.....